# Is the a limit for screen resolution?

Tags: computers, power-electronics, resolution

I think I am right in saying that 8k UHD is the highest a screen can go, so is there a limit to the number of pixels on a screen, limit to what the eye can recognise or what is physically possible?

WOuld there be any point in going up to 1M one day for example?

Comment: The limit you are asking for is probably pixel density, not resolution. Theoretically you can put "as many" pixels as you like on a panel that is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any limits in the areas you suggest. It's true that the eye's ability to perceive detail is limited, if we want to take in the entire screen at once. But we can always look at just a portion of the screen at a time, as we do with murals, large paintings, the entire scenery around us :-).  As for limits to manufacturing the screen, that's limited by power consumption (but reflective pixels can be very low power), CPU/GPU speed for calculating changing scenes, and the wiring or other schemes for communicating with the pixels. But none of those seem outright show stoppers (so to speak), just costs, which seem on a downward trajectory. Some people expect us to have vast walls of video wallpaper... and one doesn't heat categorical problems with that.

Comment: It *could* also serve as home heating.